# Declarations required for Mapbasic api calls

Tags: mapbasic

I am trying to read a serial port by using api calls createfile, readfile, getcommstate, setcommstate etc...

this all requires the proper declaration of a structure "dcb"

```
typedef struct _DCB {
 DWORD DCBlength;
 DWORD BaudRate;
 DWORD fBinary  :1;
 DWORD fParity  :1;
 DWORD fOutxCtsFlow  :1;
 DWORD fOutxDsrFlow  :1;
 DWORD fDtrControl  :2;
 DWORD fDsrSensitivity  :1;
 DWORD fTXContinueOnXoff  :1;
 DWORD fOutX  :1;
 DWORD fInX  :1;
 DWORD fErrorChar  :1;
 DWORD fNull  :1;
 DWORD fRtsControl  :2;
 DWORD fAbortOnError  :1;
 DWORD fDummy2  :17;
 WORD  wReserved;
 WORD  XonLim;
 WORD  XoffLim;
 BYTE  ByteSize;
 BYTE  Parity;
 BYTE  StopBits;
 char  XonChar;
 char  XoffChar;
 char  ErrorChar;
 char  EofChar;
 char  EvtChar;
 WORD  wReserved1;
} DCB, *LPDCB;
```

My first question is how would you declare this in mapbasic? 
Then how to determine the structures length?

Answer (score 1):

DWORD = Integer (32-bit signed)
WORD = SmallInt (16-bit signed)
BYTE do not exist in mapbasic.
CHAR may be done as string*1

You have to create another DLL, that sits between mapbasic and your DLL. This DLL should translate to a record format, where Mapbasic understands all the fields.

Comment: thanks for your response, can you explain further about these DLL's and how this might work, thanks

Comment: I have assumed this _DCB structure is part of DLL function calls? Since it uses types that mapbasic do not support, you need to write a DLL, that sits as a proxy between the DLL and mapbasic. This should remap the data structure into one that mapbasic understands. That is changing BYTES to WORDS etc.